# 1D arrays of uint32 in C

Tags: c, arrays, sockets, tcp

I'm continuously sending arrays of pixel values (160x120) as a bytestream from LabVIEW to a C-program through TCP/IP. Then I'm converting the bytes to uint32 values and printing the received data in the console application. The goal here, is that I want to divide the received data in 1D arrays, so every 1D array will consists of (160x120=19200) integer values, so it represents a frame. In better words, the array has to collect every 19200 integers of the received data and display them in the console application. Then the same array has to collect the next 19200 integers and display them in the console application and so on. I appreciate if anyone shows how to do it.

```
WSADATA wsa;
SOCKET s , new_socket;
struct sockaddr_in server , client;
int c;
int iResult;
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
unsigned int i;
size_t len;
uint32_t* p;
uint32_t value;

p = (uint32_t*)((void*)recvbuf);

do
{
    iResult = recv(new_socket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    len = iResult/sizeof(uint32_t);

    for(i=0; i < len; i++)
    {
    value = p[i];
    }
    printf("%d\n", value);

} 
while ( iResult > 0 );

closesocket(new_socket);
WSACleanup();

return 0;
```

Comment: I don't know if it makes sense to dump a picture content to console, but you should `printf` each value not only the last.

Comment: If you send pixel values of an image, why not to display the image? What sense has to dump each 4 pixels as an integer? What type is your image data?

Comment: Minor: Suspect in exceptional cases `p[i]` is a problem as the buffer `recvbuf` has `char` alignment, but it is used with `uint32_t` alignment.  Better to declare the buffer as a `uint32_t recvbuf[tbd]`.  Also use `printf("%" PRIu32 "\n", value)` or `printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long) value)`.

Comment: The image data is 32-bit unsigned integers

Answer (score 0):

This code is making lots of assumptions about the sizes and alignment of things.  On x86 systems this will work fine, but beware systems that require alignment.  It is also assuming that both systems have the same endien-ness.

To receive data chunked into 160x120 uint32_t byte chunks (assuming your DEFAULT_BUFLEN is correct):

```
int receivedCount = 0;
do
{
    iResult = recv( new_socket, 
                    &recvbuf[receivedCount],
                    DEFAULT_BUFLEN-receivedCount,
                    0 );
    if ( iResult == 0 ) break;    //0 == socket closed
    receivedCount += iResult;
    if ( receivedCount < DEFAULT_BUFLEN )
        continue;                 //still receiving full frame
    for(int i=0; i<160*120; i++)
        printf("%d\n",(unsigned int)p[i]);
    receivedCount = 0;
}
while( wantToContinueCapturingFrames );
```

This will continuously wait for data until a full frame has been received.  Once a full frame has been received it will print out the data from the frame.  If the remote system closes the connection this will exit without printing any partial frame.

This isn't really sufficient for "real" applications since it is blocking in recv waiting for data.  There's no provision to (gracefully) abort without the remote system either sending data or closing the connection, but fixing that isn't really what you are asking about here.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. 

1. How are you declaring the receivedCount?
2. Why are you declaring the unsigned char "done" and not using it ?

Comment: edited, though both answers should be fairly obvious.  I just forgot to delete the 'done' variable once I got to the bottom and didn't need it.  receivedCount would be the same type as iResult.

Comment: The code displays some zeros in the console application and then stops running due to the error in the line: 

printf("%d\n",(unsigned int)p[i]);

Unhandled exception at 0x01271729 in consoleapplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00330000.

The values of "i" and "p" are marked with red, so the error occurs there